# How to get permission list using Keycloak Token

Tags: django, keycloak

Can't get the User Permission list using Keycloak token. Getting error like  ***keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakAuthorizationConfigError: Keycloak settings not found. Load Authorization Keycloak settings.***

**Iam using python-keycloak**

## Keycloak Configuration

```
keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(server_url=config.server_url,
                            client_id=config.client_id,
                            realm_name=config.realm_name,
                            client_secret_key=config.client_secret_key,
                            verify=True)


 keycloak_openid.load_authorization_config(os.path.join(local_path, 'Dynamic_Client-authz-config.json'))

userinfo = keycloak_openid.get_permissions(token, method_token_info='introspect')
        print(userinfo)
```

## Key Cloak Setting File

```
{
  "allowRemoteResourceManagement": false,
  "policyEnforcementMode": "PERMISSIVE",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "Default Resource",
      "type": "urn:Dynamic_Client:resources:default",
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "attributes": {},
      "_id": "2c2a046f-84b2-42a8-a028-c6ae56ad63a1",
      "uris": [
        "/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "policies": [
    {
      "id": "f570c7e7-8168-4fb8-b05c-4df8be9398d0",
      "name": "Default Policy",
      "description": "A policy that grants access only for users within this realm",
      "type": "js",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
      "config": {
        "code": "// by default, grants any permission associated with this policy\n$evaluation.grant();\n"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "836d2453-ad1c-4482-b726-49875a8ba64f",
      "name": "Default Permission",
      "description": "A permission that applies to the default resource type",
      "type": "resource",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "defaultResourceType": "urn:Dynamic_Client:resources:default",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Default Policy\"]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "scopes": []
}
```

**Please find the solution for my issue**

Comment: Where did you get the "Key Cloak Settings File" from? Also - did you manage to solve your problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

so I am assuming you are looking for the roles?

If so use the introspect token , that worked for me

## Introspect Token

```
    token_info = keycloak_openid.introspect(token['access_token'])
    print(token_info['resource_access']['client-name']['roles'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the permissions using UMA ([mentioned here](https://github.com/marcospereirampj/python-keycloak)):

```
# Get UMA-permissions by token
token = keycloak_openid.token("user", "password")
permissions = keycloak_openid.uma_permissions(token['access_token'])

# Get UMA-permissions by token with specific resource and scope requested
token = keycloak_openid.token("user", "password")
permissions = keycloak_openid.uma_permissions(token['access_token'], permissions="Resource#Scope")

# Get auth status for a specific resource and scope by token
token = keycloak_openid.token("user", "password")
auth_status = keycloak_openid.has_uma_access(token['access_token'], "Resource#Scope")
```